# FFmpeg Streaming Display Issue

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, ubuntu-restricted-extras

I'm having and issue trying to initialize a FFmpeg stream. The issue I'm having is something to do with the display when I initialize it.

The error is:
`Cannot open display :0.0, error 1. :0.0: input/output error`

I'm using VNC and I'm trying to initialize this on my vps, and I'm trying to eventually steam a webpage 24/7 to YouTube.

Thanks

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu Server 15.04 (I have gnome desktop installed as well)

Comment: Any solution to this, yet?

Comment: @YanickRochon Rochon - no, have you ran into the same issue?

Comment: yes. see [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/684455/gtkrecordmydesktop-no-sound); I tried `avconv` and `ffmpeg` and I get the same error.